# How to turn my static variable selectors into dynamic variable selectors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my code, the user clicks on data. Data turns into an input box. After inputting data user presses enter and data is updated. Here is my code for this:

```
//User clicks data. An input data is shown. 
    $(document).on("click", "#hour1Name", function( event ){
        $("#hour1Name").addClass("hidden");
        $("#hour1Input").removeClass("hidden");
    });

    //User inputs data. On enter, data is updated. 
    $("#hour1Data input").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var hour1Data = document.getElementById("hour1Input").value;
        document.getElementById("hour1Name").innerHTML = hour1Data;

        $.post("UpdateTime.php",
        {
            loginName: "benjamin_lawson",
            hourData: hour1Data
        },

        function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

        })

        $("#hour1Input").addClass("hidden");
        $("#hour1Name").removeClass("hidden");
    }
    });
```

This links to:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
                <span id="hour1Data">
                    <p id="hour1Name"> <?php echo $hour1; ?> </p>
                    <input id="hour1Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
                </span>
            </div>
```

This is working great! But I have 24 pieces of data "hour1Data, hour2Data, etc..." is there a way I can modify my above jquery code so that it can react and respond to each of my data or must I duplicate the above code 24 times? Thank you!

Comment: why not give a common class to them and use `.each()`?

Comment: Can you please show me in my code how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept common classes `hName` and `hInput` for `<p>` and `<input>` tags. There is no need to use `.each()` too as I mentioned previously in comments.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
  <span id="hour1Data">
                    <p id="hour1Name" class="hName"> </p>
                    <input id="hour1Input" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(2); ?>">
  <span id="hour2Data">
                    <p id="hour2Name" class="hName"> </p>
                    <input id="hour2Input" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(3); ?>">
  <span id="hour3Data">
                    <p id="hour3Name" class="hName"> </p>
                    <input id="hour3Input" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </span>
</div>
```

And then used `.siblings()` to fetch them for each of the events.

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", ".hName", function(event) {
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
  $(this).siblings(".hInput").removeClass("hidden");
});

//User inputs data. On enter, data is updated. 
$(document).on('keypress', '.hInput', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var hourData = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings(".hName").html(hourData);
    $.post("UpdateTime.php", {
        loginName: "benjamin_lawson",
        hourData: hourData
      },

      function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

      })


    $(this).addClass("hidden");
    $(this).siblings(".hName").removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wakqujo0/2/).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much Developer107 :).

The only problem now is that when I submit my data to the sql server it needs to have a way to know if I am importing data for hour 1, hour 2, hour 3 etc. How can I do this using your current code? Perhaps I can set the ID to 1,2,3... and have it some how read the object's ID and submit this as a variable?

Comment: You can add `id` to `hourData` like this `var dataSent=hourData+$(this).attr("id")` and then send this data as `hourData`

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! This is great, I learned something new today. Again thank you so much :).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to duplicate the code. You can make this out using same class name for each span of data "hour1Data, hour2Data, etc...".  and your code would be like this.

```
 <div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
        <span id="hour1Data" class="hour-data">
          <p id="hour1Name"> <?php echo $hour1; ?> </p>
           <input id="hour1Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
                    </span>
                </div>
               <div class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
                    <span id="hour2Data" class="hour-data">
                        <p id="hour2Name"> <?php echo $hour1; ?> </p>
                        <input id="hour2Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
                    </span>
                </div>
```

//User clicks data. An input data is shown.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hour-data p").click(function( event ){
    $(this).addClass("hidden");            $(this).siblings('input').removeClass("hidden");
    });


    })

    //User inputs data. On enter, data is updated. 
    $(".hour-data input").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var hour1Data = $(this).value;
    $(this).siblings('p').html(hour1Data);

    $.post("UpdateTime.php",
    {
        loginName: "benjamin_lawson",
        hourData: hour1Data
    },

    function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

    })

    $(this).addClass("hidden");
   $(this).siblings('p').removeClass("hidden");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string concatenation to generate dynamic selectors. If you do not want to change your HTML, you can use below JS. Otherwise there are better options in other answers.

HTML

```
<span id="hour1Data">
    <p id="hour1Name"> Lorem Ipsum doller sit amet is simple dummy text </p>
    <input id="hour1Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
</span>

<span id="hour2Data">
    <p id="hour2Name"> Lorem Ipsum doller sit amet is simple dummy text </p>
    <input id="hour2Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
</span>

<span id="hour3Data">
    <p id="hour3Name"> Lorem Ipsum doller sit amet is simple dummy text </p>
    <input id="hour3Input" class="short hidden" type="text">
</span>
```

JS

```
    var num_items = 4;

    for (var i = 1; i < num_items; i++) {
        $("#hour"+i+"Data input").keypress(function (e) { proper_name(e); });
        $("#hour"+i+"Name").click(function(e) { show_input(e); });
    }

    function get_int_from_id(id) {
        i = id;
        i = i.substring(4,5);
        return i;
    }

    function show_input(e) {
        i = get_int_from_id(e.target.id);

        $("#hour"+i+"Name").addClass("hidden"); 
        $("#hour"+i+"Input").removeClass("hidden");

        $("#hour"+i+"Input").focus();            
    }

    function proper_name(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            i = get_int_from_id(e.target.id);

            var hour1Data = document.getElementById("hour"+i+"Input").value;
            document.getElementById("hour"+i+"Name").innerHTML = hour1Data;

            $.post("UpdateTime.php",
            {
                loginName: "benjamin_lawson",
                hourData: hour1Data
            },

            function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

            })

            $("#hour"+i+"Input").addClass("hidden");
            $("#hour"+i+"Name").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    }
```